# Question about audio files and Final Cut

Tags: final, cut, omf

hi! I have a doubt about Final, omf s and original audio files.
I have received a project from a client. They send me omf s at 48 khz/16 bits, because the sequence where they edited in Final Cut was set up in that way, but the original audio files were recorded at 48khz/24 bits.
My question is this: if the Final Cut´s project was set up at 16 bits, the original audio files were rendered to match this bit depht? And what happens if they change the sequence setting to 24 bits, or the omf s export setting? It would rendered the already rendered file to match 24 bits again? or it would link to the original 24 bits audio file?
I hope that my questions are clear enough!
Thanks a lot in advance!
Bye!

Answer (score 1):

My guess? They will probably keep it in 16 bits anyway.

Comment: I concur.  I'll hit up one of my buddies today to find out.